# How do I target the parent of the element to apply styles to it depending on the state of its child?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here, the `div.add-user` contains the form for registration. I wanted to apply styles to `div.add-user` when the input is either `:focus` or `:valid`, but I failed to use `input:focus + .add-user`. I tried to google the problem, but it seems like there is no solution for that. Is that even possible in CSS or should I use JS instead?

```
<div class="add-user">
   <form id="add-user" action="/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
       <div>
           <input type="text" name="input-name" id="input-name" required>
           ...
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not possible. CSS styles only apply one-way in the document tree, and that is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css `:focus-within` psudeo class .. [Read MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

See example =>

**HTML**

```
<div class="add-user">
  <form id="add-user" action="/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="input-name" id="input-name" required>
      ...
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .add-user {
    background: red;

  }
  form {
    border: 1px solid;
    color: gray;
    padding: 4px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }

  form:focus-within {
    background: #ff8;
    color: black;
  }

  input {
    margin: 4px;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not think about this before, but now I'm familiar with :focus-within pseudo-class

Comment: @Malik Usmonov I don't think the question was duplicate it  has to do nothing with the question tagged as duplicate